# Parallel processes using semaphores in C

Tags: c, semaphore

I have a big problem with semaphores in C. Here is the link to inspiration of my code: http://cse.unl.edu/~ylu/csce351/notes/Solution%20for%20Building%20H2O.pdf.

There are two similar codes for hydrogen and oxygen. This is the idea: There are processes generated for oxygen and hydrogen and they are created in different time. When there are 2 hydrogens and 1 oxygen they call function `bond()`. But they have to wait for them. After the condition is evaluated as false it is supposed to switch to another process (or at least that is how I understand it). But in my code it continues to the next command which causes that it won't wait to all processes that I need. It prints to output after every process that is created even if it is supposed to wait. Does anyone know know whats wrong there?

(I can post more of the code if this is not enough.)

OXYGEN CODE:(hydrogen is similar)

```
sem_wait(mutex);
if ((*hydrogen >=2) && (*oxigen>=1))
{
    (*count_c)++;
    *count_cur_h-=2;
    sem_post(hydrel);
    sem_post(hydrel);
    *count_cur_o-=1;
    sem_post(oxrel);
}
else
{
    (*count_c)++;
    sem_post(mutex);   // This is the place where it is supposed
                       // to release and continue to another process,
                       // but it goes to the next command.
}

sem_wait(oxrel);
bond();
sem_wait(barrier);

//semaphores are initialized like this:
sem_init(mutex,1,1);
sem_init(oxrel,1,1);
sem_init(hydrel,1,2);
sem_init(barrier,1,3);
```

Comment: How do you define those mutexes, where are they? They should be located in a shared memory since you're creating mutexes that are shared between processes. Also, when you say *continue to another process* in your comment, do you mean waking up another process (waiting on `mutex`)? Another thing, you acquire the mutex but release it only in else condition. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Semaphores  are in shared memory.  And I meant by that keep waiting till there wont be 2 hydrogens and oxygen.  It shoul be intended behavour- when you look into link there is the same thing(the same thing is in book" the little book of semaphores" which is used as reference in our school project)

Comment: Also, where is `barrier` released in your code? The code in your link uses `mutex.signal()` instead of `barrier.wait()`, which your code does. Another note: `sem_post` won't switch to another process, the caller will keep running. The code in the link seems to rely on mutex-acquiring to stop the current process.

Comment: barrier is released in bond function. Yeah, it uses barrier.wait, but that is just an addon. This code I posted is for oxygen and  code for hydrogen uses mutex.signal(). I know it wont switch to another process, but it it supposed to release the process(I think).

Answer (score 1):

sem_post is not a blocking call. sem_wait is the blocking call. If the value of semaphore is zero when sem_wait is called, the function that called it will block. sem_post is used to release another thread that is blocking waiting on sem_wait when the semaphore value is zero, but it does *not* block itself. The sem_post call is used to 'wake up a thread waiting on sem-wait' but then continues onwards, and both threads will then run at the same time (if you have at least 2 logical CPUs). If you want the thread that called sem_post to block at that point you will need to do something else (like add yet another semaphore).